# Advice with lists, for loops, and user lists iput in order to create a calculator that calculates average

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
knowledge= [100,90]
knowledge=sum(knowledge)
for n in knowledge:
    print ('Your average is' + knowledge/n*100)

thinking= [96,90,97]
thinking=sum(thinking)
for n in thinking:
    print ('Your average is' + thinking/ n*100)
```

I am trying to build a very simple calculator that calculates your average. Instead of me putting in the marks, I would like to know how I can ask the user to input their marks and then the marks are added and divided by the number of marks *100. 
I would like to know what I am doing wrong. 
And I was also wondering how I could add the printed values and multiply them by how much each category is worth. Knowledge for example is worth 60% and Thinking is worth 40%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are doing wrong is changing knowledge from a list `[100,90]` into an int `190`

`for n in 190` is not a valid statement

furthermore

`thinking% n*100`  is not the same as `thinking/n*100` , the first uses a modulo operator (`%`) and it should use a division operator (`/`)

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
mean = sum(knowledge)/len(knowledge)
```

Also, if you can use the numpy package:

```
import numpy
scores_list = [10,120,50,80,500,40]
scores_array = numpy.array(scores_list)
scores_mean = numpy.mean(scores_array)
scores_std = numpy.std(scores_array)
scores_min = numpy.min(scores_array)
scores_max = numpy.max(scores_array)
```

Comment: in the 2.x series yes, 3.x no

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's the confusion here.

```
>>> thinking= [96,90,97]
>>> average=sum(thinking)/float(len(thinking))
>>> average
94.33333333333333
>>> round(average, 2)
94.33
>>> average=sum(thinking)/len(thinking)
>>> average
94
```

Answer (score 1):

```
knowledge= [100,90]
knowledge=sum(knowledge)
```

`knowledge` is now an integer, so when you try to do `for n in knowledge`, you're trying to iterate over an integer, but you can't do this.

Your print statement, I believe, is missing a `%d` for string formatting to take place.

```
print ('Your average is %d' + % knowledge % n*100)
```

This is the same for the second loop too.

---

To get the average of a list, just do `sum(thinking)/len(thinking)` (or `sum(thinking)/float(len(thinking))` if you're dealing with floats